# Instantiating a class does not work, constructor parameter is interface

Tags: java, interface, ejml

i tried to create a instance of a class that implemented an interface, but the problem is that the constructor takes a parameter which is the interface itself.

Information: I dont want to implement the interface, class or funcinality by myself, because the library [EJML](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/alg/dense/linsol/LinearSolver_B64_to_D64.html) has implemented it already, i just want to use the class and the functions.

```
    public class myMatrixFactory{
        public void do(){
            //Does not work because LinearSolver_B64_to_D64() needs a interface as parameter
            // parameter is LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F> which is an interface
            LinearSolver_B64_to_D64 ls = new LinearSolver_B64_to_D64(????);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the funky manual? http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Solving_Linear_Systems

Comment: Thank, as i am very new to programming, i am not familiar using the javadoc and manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an object of a class that implements the required interface and pass it to the constructor.

According to the link you provided you need an object of type `LinearSolver<BlockMatrix64F>` so you should take a look at this classes javadoc and choose one of the implementing classes.

Comment: I would say `LinearSolverFactory` should be used

Comment: Helped me alot, also referring to the manual makes everthing clear!